# How does JavaScript object history stores an URL into its stack?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, browser-history

I have this history logs in the `window.history` object with 5 as my current page.

```
5) http://myapp.com/great-new-story/01242020.html
4) http://myapp.com/great-new-story/01052020.html
3) http://myapp.com/great-new-story/12012019.html
2) http://myapp.com/allnews.html
1) http://myapp.com
```

Then I want to go to page `allnews.html` (or no.2) , will the `allnews.html` be logged in No. 6?

Or it will not be logged and will use (no. 2) since allnews was already in the stack?

Comment: Can't you try it out by yourself via the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)?

Comment: In addtion: Why is this important to know?

Comment: @Uwe Keim , because there's been an error regarding my usage of history object.

Comment: example: Here's my history

7) --> when I clicked the Resume button in the Help page, should redirect to Login Page (5), since it was the last page I was into , but , it redirected to (4) or Purchase Confirmation
6) Help page (then as I Log-in again, there has been some error with my credentials and proceeded to Help page, or I just intentionally added some wrong credentials)
5) Login Page (because suddenly I quit my purchase transaction and proceeded back to Login)
4) Purchase confirmation
3) Purchasing of Materials page 
2) User Verification (After Login)
1) Login page

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple experiment:

1. Count the length of the history.

   ```
   window.history.length();    //4
   ```
2. Go some steps back

   ```
   window.history.go(-2);
   ```
3. Get the length again. Its still 4!

**Answer:**

Navigating the history would not increase the depth.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it will push in a new one, because of the simple fact, this is also used for the back and forward navigation buttons, so it should be like that, also I just checked it.
Created a new tab > open google.com
searched something and basically it redirected, so then window.history length increased,
Then In omnibar . search bar I wrote google.com -- the length of window.history incremented once again.

And as I said, it should be that for back and forward stack maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help guys, really appreciate it :y: :)

However, I have found the answer to my problem.
And it's about using the `location.replace` , instead of using `location.assign` when redirecting to a site.
I have found out that `location.replace` -

> removes the URL of the current document from the document history,
>   meaning that it is not possible to use the "back" button to navigate
>   back to the original document.

as per w3schools. That's why I started to use `Location.assign` , where after I click the link, then click the `history.back` , it redirected to the correct previous site.